# passing username in url, is this a security concern?

Tags: php

I am a newly developer looking for some help.
I have tried to search this issue, however i did not find anything satisfactory.

What i have got is basically:
Registration form. A user enters his details and registers for my website.
If the fields are too short a error is processed and redirected the same page with a variable in the url.
Then i get the url variable on same page and display the error.

However when i refresh the page the form information is gone, the error array works correctly and displays on page however i would have to pass the username,email etc.. in the url.

So my question is: would it be a problem to pass firstname,surname,username,email into the url so it can be displayed in the form after refreshing ? I know how to do this i was just wondering if it should be done or not.

**Edit**

An example of my code. But I would like to use this for username to hold the data after submission.

```
if (strlen($firstName) <= 3)
{
$error_array_4 = array("er4" => "t");
}

header('Location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?'.$error_array_4.'');

if(isset($_GET['er4']) && $_GET['er4'] == "t")
{
echo "<div id='errorContainer'>Your firstname is too short</div>";
}
```

Comment: It's safer using POST if you don't "need" to use a GET method.

Comment: You could save them in the SESSION to do the same

Comment: well, if the resulting page links anywhere, and those links get clicked, then you'd be leaking all of those query parameters in the http referer. so yeah, probably not a good idea. why not pass the data around via POST, or keep it all server-side in the session?

Comment: session is not a option as it affects website performance if there are many users.

Comment: @user3741224 If you truly cares about performance, PHP is not the right tool for the job. And also, where is this coming from? Have you tested what happens when there are many users and found that sessions are the bottleneck, or are you just assuming?

Comment: An example of what i am asking is here:
https://signin.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?SignIn&errmsg=8&pUserId=fgdasfdsaf&co_partnerId=2&siteid=3&pageType=-1&pa1=&i1=-1&UsingSSL=1&k=1&favoritenav=&ru=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.co.uk%2F&pp=&bshowgif=0&gu=0&ifh=0

Comment: sessions have almost zero overhead, unless you're storing massive amounts of data in the session. and if file-based sessions are too slow, there's other methods of speeding up session storage/retrieval

Comment: In that ebay link you can see username is stored in the url, What i am wondering is if it would be a problem for me to do the same but for a registration page?

Comment: Also i have searched on google regarding file session and it could be a problem. I am just wondering if it would be a issue to store the fields in a url so the form can get it and fill the field.

Comment: Session doesn't affect performance unless you're storing ridiculous amounts of information in it, or you have very long running pages. Whoever told you that it did was clueless.

Comment: Okay, so should i use sessions for error messages as well? Assuming each user will have 10 sessions will this affect performance later on?

Comment: If it's on a "as per user", there shouldn't be any performance loss. You should also make sure that your DB is properly indexed, as am pretty sure you are using a DB.

Comment: Each user will only have 1 session. Do you mean each user will have 10 variables in the session?  Big deal. That's nothing.

Comment: I mean they could hit your page and get a session, clear cookies, hit the page and get another, clear cookies, and do that 100 times. But who cares, since all those sessions will be empty and will expire after 30 minutes anyway (unless you change the default session expiration to something else).

Comment: Okay i see, so realisticly how manny sessions can a cheap server handle?

Comment: @Fred-ii- A POST is no safer than a GET.  The data is still in the HTTP Request HEADER. Using the Session is most secure as the data is only accessible on the Server.  Cookie values are also in every HTTP Request HEADER and in any HTTP Response HEADER that Sets the Cookie Value.

Comment: @Misunderstood Read what Marc wrote in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27950761/passing-username-in-url-is-this-a-security-concern#comment44296596_27950761), my sentiments exactly.

Comment: This question should be closed as either being too broad, or primarily opinion-based.

Comment: I am sorry if there is anything wrong with the question.

Comment: Concerning performance: "what's slow for a computer is often fast enough for a human" - _some intelligent guy_. There's way too much buzz going on about 'performance'. Do you really think a modern computer system will break into a sweat because of the cute little scripts we're talking about here? C'mon...

Comment: @user3741224 no in principle it's a good question, but it turns out to raise hefty debate about certain topics. It might be wise to let this question be closed down and, using the answers and comments, redefine your question to a narrower scope.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Not sure you realize Mark B is wrong.  POST and GET HTTP Headers BOTH contain the Query/POST data. The Referer is not any concern because if Referer were enabled the same query string would be superfluous. If HTTPS is being used then the data is available only to the server and the user that entered the data.  I do not see a problem.

Comment: @Misunderstood Please take it up with `@ him`. I'm done with this question and closed this tab from my browser 10 minutes ago. Way too broad and primarily opinion-based. However, the OP should look into [**XSS (Cross Site Scripting)**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) also.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want the error to remain after refreshing?

The error pertains to this very latest submission, it only makes sense in the context of that submission. If I reload the page (or for that instance, close the tab and enter the form again), why would I need to see the same error? Showing the fresh form makes more sense to me.

However, if you insist, there are several approaches you can take:

- Validate client-side, and save the errors into `localStorage`, localStorage is kept client-side so only that client will ever see it. (Note that this doesn't absolve you from validating server-side too, it's just that the server-side error handling doesn't need to be as nice)
- Use sessions, that's what they're for mate.

Passing those parameters in the query is undesirable because:

- It creates long and ugly URLs, which you may not care about but...
- It may reveal sensitive information (like passwords) in the URL, which is prone to shoulder surfing.

Comment: What you mean by client-side validation? I thought sessions were not client side but retrieved from the server?

Comment: Yes, what I mean is that you do the validation on the client using JavaScript, and don't allow submission unless validation passes. Note that you still have to validate server-side though, validating with JS is not secure (it's more of a convenience feature for the user).

Comment: Yes ofcourse i know validating client side only is not safe. Should i take into consideration if javascript is disabled?

Comment: Less than 0.5% of the users have JavaScript disabled, so I wouldn't sweat it.

Comment: @SecondRikudo I count myself in being part of that percentage ;-) Only fired-up on demand.

Answer (score 0):

While a lot of people mentioned he should use POST instead of GET, no one told him how. Which I will do now since he is *a newly developer looking for some help*.

In your html, where you have your form, add the attribute `method` with the value `POST`:

```
<form method="POST" ...
```

Of course you will need to change your php scripts to use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET` after that.

The difference is `GET` (which is default when you omit `method=`) gets appended to URL like ?name=foo&action=bar but `POST` will be send with headers.

Now when you hit refresh on the resulting page, your browser will ask you to submit the data again.

Comment: i am already using post method on the form

Comment: This is no "better" or "safer" than a GET from a security viewpoint. The only thing it prevents is the username being visible in the resource URI itself.

Comment: I thought this was about error messages (e.g. *your username is already in use*) dissapearing when refreshing the page. Thus my assumption you're using GET.

Comment: @user3741224 Is this really a use case of your application that users refresh the page when they're on the form? Don't they just fill in the missing field and hit submit or enter?

Comment: SO would a $_Post not show the variable in the url? I am sorry about these questions but i am getting more confused lol..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using procedural PHP code it makes this an easy problem to solve (this can be done using OOP ofcourse). Consider this small amount of code. This should all be in the same file, no redirects should be done as it would break the logic.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $errors = [];

    // Assign posted values to variables
    $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    /*
     * Error checking here. If an error occurs you update your errors array and 
     * leave the posted as it is.
     */ 
    if(strlen($username) < 4 || strlen($username) > 30) {
        $errors[] = 'The username must be between 4 and 30 characters in length.';
    }

    // Do your registration logic here.

    // If all is good and well redirect to another page (login page maybe)

}else{

   $username = null;
   $email    = null;
   // Add any other required variables here...

}
?>
```

Then in your HTML form you do the following:

```
<form method="POST" action="">

    <p>Username:</p>
    <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" />

    <p>Email:</p>
    <input type="text" name=email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
```

Pay attention to the `value` attribute of the `input` HTML tag. You can echo the value of the input field here.

This will ensure the variables `$username` and `$email` is always defined and as their default value equals `NULL` you can echo them to the screen without worry. Then when the page is posted the `$username` and `$email` variables are overwritten with the values provided by the user and displayed if an error occurred.

**Bonus info**

On youtube there is a small series where a registration and login system is created. REMEMBER this is a very poor system and should only be used to learn the very basics and never be used on a live server!
There is also much more than what you asked about as he covers database interaction slightly, but forgets about one basic thing (which I will describe in a bit). But you can use this to get the basic understanding of what happens behind the scenes.

[PHPAcadamy: Registration & Login System](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngqeWUIDlnk&ab_channel=phpacademy)

If you feel like it you can read a bit about the two following things on Google (this is some very good basic knowledge).

1. How to sanitize input
2. Output escaping.

Hope this helps. I know it may be a little intimidating and quite weird to understand. Feel free to ask me if this is too little information.

Comment: So would this not pass the variable in the header like i was doing?

Comment: @user3741224 No, this would not be stored anywhere other than that one time the PHP script runs. No headers, URLs, sessions or whatever you can imagine. Just plain PHP :D

Comment: @user3741224 I added a little bonus info you can have a look at, but know that this is VERY FAR from a solid system and only shows the basics.

Comment: Hello, I have used this plain php example before and then i have updated it to redirect to same page but get error var in url and display on page to prevent Form Resubmission.

Comment: You should remove the redirect completely as the page submits to itself.

Comment: I have used the redirect in order to prevent form resubmission...

Comment: @user3741224 I have updated the answer to show where redirects should happen. If you have used a redirect to avoid resubmission there is something else wrong that should not be affected by the code shown as it is self contained.

Comment: I dont think you understood. I have redirected it to the same page containing the errors in order to avoid form resubmission. Your code will enable me to resend the form on refresh.

Comment: Okay now I understand you. Well that is a restriction with this approach. If you redirect to prevent resend the form on refresh the code I have presented cannot be used. Sorry for the (then) wrong answer :D

Comment: Yes, so would you have any suggestions on how i could keep the fields input on refresh?
Currently i am doing it via URL with the errors displayed. Should i store the fields in sessions,cookies or URL ??

Comment: I would go for the session. Read the value and delete on the next page as soon as possible to avoid the session getting full of stale data. The session would also ensure pretty looking URLs which helps on google search rankings.

Comment: Okay clears alot of things up. Thanks, So will it affect google search rankings if the URL is big after it submits? When you first go to the register page the url will be plain, only after hitting the submit button the url will get bigger.

Comment: I dont know how exactly how that works, but I have always been told to avoid non-consistent query string. And in this example the username could be anything. Go read about CEO friendly urls on Google.

Answer (score -1):

If HTTPS is being used, there is no security issue regarding User Name.

If HTTPS is not being used, questions regarding security are moot because no security exists to question.

There is no way to secure the GET Query String or POST data when not using HTTPS.